# I have error when I use function playsound()

Tags: python, playsound

At first, it records and plays the audio normally, but when I play it again after 'recommencer/o', this problem appears to me ' raise

```
PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 259 for command:
        play "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\PSn1gs6vpj.wav" wait
    Le pilote ne peut pas reconnaître le paramètre de commande spécifié.'
```

```
import pyaudio
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import wave
import librosa
import librosa.display
# import speaker_verification_toolkit.tools as svt
# import IPython.display as ipd
from playsound import playsound


def main():
    """
    # On definit les chemins d'acces au différentes hyper parametre
    """

    # On définit les specs de notre fichier audio de test
    format = pyaudio.paInt16
    channels = 2
    rate = 44100
    chunk = 1024
    recordTime = 2
    soundPath = '.\\testAudio\\test.wav'

    record(format, channels, rate, chunk, recordTime, soundPath)


def record(format, channels, rate, chunk, recordTime, soundPath):
    while True:

        audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

        # Début enregistrement
        stream = audio.open(format=format, channels=channels, rate=rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)

        os.system('cls')

        # Enregistrement de la voix
        frames = []
        for i in tqdm(range(0, int(rate / chunk * recordTime)), "> Enregistrement... "):
            data = stream.read(chunk)
            frames.append(data)

        # On stop l'enregistrement
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
        print("Enregistrement OK")

        # On enregistre l'extrait audio en fichier wav
        waveFile = wave.open(soundPath, 'wb')
        waveFile.setnchannels(channels)
        waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(format))
        waveFile.setframerate(rate)
        waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        waveFile.close()
        playsound(
            r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\tp\testAudio\test.wav')

        print("\n> Traitement les données...")

        x, sr = librosa.load(soundPath)
        f = librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr)
        print(f.shape)
        # Display the MFCCs
        plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        librosa.display.specshow(f, sr=sr, x_axis='time')
        plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
        plt.show()
        again = input("\nRecommencer ? (O/N) ")
        if again == 'n':
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    # MAIN
    """
    main()
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message. It should start with a line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/mémoire tp nv/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/testvoice.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()

Comment: File "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/mémoire tp nv/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/testvoice.py", line 27, in main
    record(format, channels, rate, chunk, recordTime, soundPath)

Comment: File "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/mémoire tp nv/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/Keyword-voice-recognition-master/testvoice.py", line 60, in record

Comment: r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\mémoire tp nv\Keyword-voice-recognition-master\Keyword-voice-recognition-master\testAudio\test.wav')
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 44, in _playsoundWin
    _playsoundWin(tempPath, block)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 73, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'play {}{}'.format(sound, ' wait' if block else ''))

Comment: File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include an error message with correct formatting. Do not try to use the comments to add more information to the post. Please note well that this is **not a discussion forum**, and we are not having a threaded conversation.